# How does waiting on Task.Result affect nested async/await methods?

Tags: c#, async-await

This is a bit long winded, but here goes....

Given that I have an interface like so:

```
public interface IWebClientHelper
{
    TPayload Get<TPayload>(string url);
}
```

Where the implementation of `Get` makes a call to the supplied URL, which will return a response containing a Json object of type `TPayload`), and that Json is deserialized into `TPayload` and then returned.

I would like to make the implementation of the `Get` method asynchronous (or more specifically make the HTTP call contained within the `Get` method asynchronous), but as I understand it, that would require that the signature of the `Get` method be changed to:

```
Task<TPayload> Get<TPayload>(string url);
```

I am aiming to keep the interface as it is, so I created a second interface:

```
public interface IAsyncWebClientHelper
{
    Task<TPayload> Get<TPayload>(string url);
}
```

and injected that into my implementation of `IWebClientHelper`. So now my implementation of `IWebClientHelper` looks like this:

```
public TPayload Get<TPayload>(string url)
{
    return _asyncWebClientHelper.Get<TPayload>(url).Result;
}
```

and the `Get` method of `_asyncWebClientHelper` contains the line

```
message = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
```

So what I am unclear on is this: Am I correct in thinking that the line `return _asyncWebClientHelper.Get<TPayload>(url).Result` will block the execution until that method returns? Or will the `await` keyword inside that method release the thread until it has received a response from the url?

Comment: That is sync-over-async which is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, using `Result` means that your method will block. However, it's quite possible that means it will actually cause a deadlock. You haven't told us much about the context, but if you're in a context where after the `await` you need to return back to the same thread, but that thread is blocked due to the `Result`, you're basically deadlocking on yourself. You need to be *very* careful where you use any blocking calls such as the `Result` property or the `Wait()` method.

Fundamentally, trying to use asynchrony without making your interface asynchronous is tricky/pointless. You'd be much better off embracing asynchrony whole-heartedly, or sticking with the synchronous version. After all, if you're going to keep a thread blocked until the asynchronous task has completed, what's the benefit of the asynchrony in the first place?

Comment: I thought this may be the case, just wanted to make sure before I set about replacing all 64 references to the synchronous interface...

Comment: @paynecrl97: You have my sympathy. Converting code from sync to async is never fun.